# Where is the EnversSchemaGenerator in Hibernate 5.1?

Tags: java, hibernate, generator, database-schema, hibernate-envers

The [Envers 5.1 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers) states that you should use the `org.hibernate.envers.tools.hbm2ddl.EnversSchemaGenerator` to export a database schema programmatically.

But the class is not there anymore! Really  ;-)

Maybe it was not adjusted to the [schema management changes](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.1/migration/#changes-to-schema-management-tooling)?
How do I substitute the class with Hibernate 5.1?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export tables in a sql file in Hibernate 5.xx you can use the following code

```
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySetting("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"); // dialect

MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(registryBuilder.build());

PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourceLoader = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(null, resourceLoader, metadataSources).scanPackages("com.xxx");

Metadata metadata = metadataSources.buildMetadata();

new SchemaExport().setFormat(true).setOutputFile("export.sql").createOnly(EnumSet.of(TargetType.STDOUT, TargetType.SCRIPT), metadata);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To export schema programatically ,alternate way is

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =(StandardServiceRegistryImpl) new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .build();
MetadataImplementor metadata = (MetadataImplementor) new   MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).buildMetadata();
SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(metadata);
schemaExport.setOutputFile("hbm2schema.sql");
schemaExport.create(true, true);
( (StandardServiceRegistryImpl) serviceRegistry ).destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of Hibernate you had to generate the sql from the entities and those from Envers separatly.

But now it is not necessary anymore. Just generate them like mentioned and the envers will be generated along with them. (_AUTH tables)